# Trying to log this javascript variable in Applescript but its logging as (*missing value*)

Tags: javascript, applescript

tell application "Google Chrome" 
set myVar to execute Javascript "document.getElementsByTagName('input')"
log "did it"
log myVar
end tell

Comment: The result of your javascript is a complex type, and if you can update it to return a scalar value, Would be weird to try and return a JSON object to Applescript. I can give you a code snippet to make it work for scalar value.

Comment: I am trying to get a list of all the input elements on a webpage. Is there anyway I can do that with AppleScript? Perhaps parse the JSON?

Comment: You could probably serialize the JSON object into a string, pass it back to AppleScript, then deserialize it into an array of records.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, if you could replace the result with a scalar value, like read an attribute or value of an HTML element, you could do:

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    set myVar to execute tab 1 of window 1 javascript "1"

    log "did it"
    log myVar
end tell
```

For simplicity, it is just returning the `1` literal. You can change the javascript code that returns a scalar value like: `document.getElementById('someId').value`